# Javascript: How to detect if the current page has a form with particular name and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which looks like this

```
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" />
    ... other stuff
</form>
```

In a common `$(document).ready(function()` which is shared between multiple pages, I want to detect if I am in a page which has a form with the following characteristics

- action="/aa//bbcc" & id="Form1"
- an input with name="somename" and value="somevalue"

How do I do this?

The page has access to jquery also if that is required. Without jquery is also fine.

Comment: No-one tells that how he will check the current page and match it ? Because it's a common `$(document).ready(function(){..});` so OP have to check that-one first

Comment: @AlivetoDie what do you mean?

Comment: user93353 if you are asking me what it means , then you can go for any-one answer. All are correct. Just forget about my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can select the form with id and check if the node list returned is of length more than 0. Then you can check if it has an input with name 'somename' and then check if the value of that input is 'somevalue'.

```js
   if ($('#Form1[action="/aa/bbcc"]').length > 0 && $('#Form1').has("input[name='somename']") &&
    $("#Form1 input[name='somename']").val() === "somevalue"){
       console.log('found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" />
... other stuff
</form>
```

Comment: You've forgotten the second part of the question: *an input with name="somename" and value="somevalue"*

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function isFormPresent() {
    return !!$("form#Form1[action='/aa/bbcc'] input[name='somename'][value='somevalue']").length
  }
  console.log(isFormPresent());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with in selector

**For single line**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('form[action="/aa/bbcc"]').find('input[name="somename"][value="somevalue"]').length > 0) {
    console.log('ok')
  } else {
    console.log('not ok')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" />
</form>
```

**Separate**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('form[action="/aa/bbcc"]').length > 0) {
    console.log('action ok')
  }
  if ($('form[action="/aa/bbcc"]').find('input[name="somename"]').length > 0) {
    console.log('input name ok')
  }
  if ($('form[action="/aa/bbcc"]').find('input[value="somevalue"]').length > 0) {
    console.log('input value ok')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" />

</form>
```

Comment: its common right.But each time page loading .its share individually to document .each js script as a new js to document.

Comment: The second snippet is not the same as first snippet.

Comment: @guest271314 ..ya  ...i was mention on with heading .you could see that..

Comment: @prasad `<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" />
  <input type="hidden" value="somevalue" />
</form>` would not return expected result for requirement _"an input with name="somename" and value="somevalue""_, unless OP means a second element by "and"

Comment: @guest271314 ...ya .That's why i was posted with second method `separate `.its your code accept with second method :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check the following example .

```js
if (document.querySelector("#Form1") && (document.getElementById("Form1").getAttribute("action") == '/aa/bbcc')) {

  var elem = document.getElementById("Form1").children[0];
  if (elem.getAttribute('name') == 'somename' && elem.getAttribute('value') == 'somevalue') {
    // code to exceute
    console.log('in result');
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="/aa/bbcc" method="post" id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue" /> ... other stuff
</form>
```